# How to multiply a matrix with more than one vector to obtain a list of matrices?

Tags: r

Assume we have the following matrix:

```
m=matrix(1:6,ncol=2)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

Using `sweep` we can multiply the matrix `m` with some vector `v`:

```
v=c(3,4)

sweep(m , MARGIN=2, v , `*`)

# Output :
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    3   16
    [2,]    6   20
    [3,]    9   24
```

I am searching to do this with more than one vector. For example:

```
v_matrix=matrix(data=c(3,4,7,8),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

v_matrix

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    7    8
```

The expected output is :

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   16
[2,]    6   20
[3,]    9   24
[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   32
[2,]   14   40
[3,]   21   48
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the `v_matrix` by row in `apply`, and then use the `sweep` on the row values which is a `vector` with 'm' as `matrix`

```
do.call("c", apply(v_matrix, 1, function(x) list(sweep(m, MARGIN = 2, x, `*`))))
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3   16
#[2,]    6   20
#[3,]    9   24

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    7   32
#[2,]   14   40
#[3,]   21   48
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `Map`

```
> Map(function(x, y) t(x * y), list(t(m)), data.frame(t(v_matrix)))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   16
[2,]    6   20
[3,]    9   24

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   32
[2,]   14   40
[3,]   21   48
```